# Python Table Formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, spyder

I'm trying to subtotal a column from a table and format the sum numbers using Python in Spyder.

I have this example table in .csv file format:

[image]

I would like to subtotal Column5 at each change in Column1.
Then format the sum numbers to whole numbers and show the result as a new table showing Column1 and Columb5 sum values only.

I got as far as using

```
pd.read_csv  #to get the file and  
.groupby("Column1")["Column5"].sum()   #to do the subtotal
```

but I'm not sure how to format the result values to show as whole numbers and I'm not sure how to print this as a table.

This is the end result I'd like:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by `at each change in Column1` but what you did exactly gave you the expected result. For instance,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                   'Column3': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'Column5': [4, 4, 2, 2]})
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("Column1")["Column5"].sum()).reset_index()
```

gives you,

[image]